# Why does "WHERE (Time_Stamp >= TDateTime-variable)" ignore fractional seconds?

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi, sql-server-2000

Using Delphi 6 and Microsoft SQL Server 2000.

I need to extract records where a TDateTime Field is > a passed TDateTime, "FromDate".
It fails as if the fractional part of the seconds of the passed TDateTime are always zero.
Debug printouts confirm that the fractions are there.

The WHERE part ignores the fraction part of :Fdate.
Assume the following 3 records:
Record 1: Time_Stamp is 1.2
Record 2: Time_Stamp is 1.4
Record 3: Time_Stamp is 1.6

The value 1.3 is then sent to the Query in :Fdate.
The resulting dataset returns ALL 3 records.
I expected only records 2 and 3 since 1.3 > 1.2

The 'Time_Stamp' field in database is a SQL 'datetime' field.
Everything works perfectly for integer seconds,
i.e. one record per second, or less often, when the decimal fraction is unimportant.

Can anyone point out where my error is?

The SQL statement is generated by code (shown below) as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 6 * FROM T_TransactionLog  
INNER JOIN T_LookUp_TransTypes  
ON T_TransactionLog.TransType = T_LookUp_TransTypes.TransType  
WHERE (Time_Stamp >= :Fdate)  
AND T_TransactionLog.TransType IN (  
3,  
4,  
5  
)  
AND LockerNo < 60001  
ORDER BY Time_Stamp ASC
```

The code is as follows:

```
Query.Connection := Sys_DB_Form.ADOConnection;  
DataSource.DataSet := Query;  

Query.SQL.Add('SELECT TOP ' + IntToStr(cNoTransactions) + ' * FROM
  T_TransactionLog');  

Query.SQL.Add('INNER JOIN T_LookUp_TransTypes');  
Query.SQL.Add('ON T_TransactionLog.TransType =  
  T_LookUp_TransTypes.TransType');  

Query.SQL.Add('WHERE (Time_Stamp ' + S_Condition + ' :Fdate)');  
Query.SQL.Add('AND T_TransactionLog.TransType IN (');  
Query.SQL.Add(IntToStr(ord(Apl_TrLog.ttEA)) + ',');  
Query.SQL.Add(IntToStr(ord(Apl_TrLog.ttMO)) + ',');  
Query.SQL.Add(IntToStr(ord(Apl_TrLog.ttMC)));  
Query.SQL.Add(')');  
Query.SQL.Add('AND LockerNo < ' +
IntToStr(Apl_Config.cLNoOfFirstgate));  
if Locker <> 0 then  
  begin  
    Query.SQL.Add('AND LockerNo = ' + IntToStr(Locker));  
  end;  
Query.SQL.Add(S_OrderBy);  

Query.Parameters.FindParam('Fdate').Value := FromDate; // <<< Fail???? 

Query.SQL.SaveToFile(GetApplicationDataPath + 'Sql.txt');  
try  
  Query.Open;  
except  
  ShowMessage('Query open fail on ME Show Transaction log');  
end;
```

Comment: What datatype is `:FDate`? Running straight SQL I'm getting the expected results as long as the data is correct.

Comment: @Tom H. I don't know. That particular line was taken from an example somewhere.I have unsuccessfully tried to understand how to use FindParam. I do assign a TDateTime to it, hoping it can handle it, which it can if there are no fractions. Should .Value be something else?

Comment: Why do you need `FindParam` at all? Use `ParamByName`, since you know the param exists.

Comment: What happens if you test in Sql directly e.g. "if Time_Stamp > somevalue select 'after' else select 'not after' "?

Comment: @Ken White. I do not understand the Parameter property. I always believed the 'Fdate' name is something I need to add in order for the Query to have something to look for. Since you say I should 'know' it exists, where is it? Should I somehow add it to Query after I create it? Is that were I go wrong? Om the other hand it works fine except for the fractional issue.

Comment: You added it in your SQL, when you added `:FDate`, so you know it exists. `FindParam` is only needed if you're not sure the parameter exists; it returns the parameter if it's found or nil instead, so you can't just blindly use it. `ParamByName` raises an exception if the parameter doesn't exist.

Comment: You can try adding: `Query.params.parambyname('FDate').datatype:=TDateTime`, although I don't know if it will be smart enough to realize that you only want the time portion for your query.

Comment: @Ken White. I tried ParamByName and also set the datatype to  dtDateTime: ParamByName('Fdate').DataType := ftDateTime. Unfortunately no change.

Comment: @Tom H. I added the datatype, except TDateTime does not compile. ftDateTime does. Also, I do not want only the time portion, I want date and time, and particular the fraction part of the seconds, the milliseconds. It is the milliseconds that create the problem. The program behaves as if TDateTime was truncated, milliseconds cleared to zero, before the Query executes.

Comment: I'm confused. Re-reading your question, it's pretty unclear what data type is in your column in the DB. A TDateTime is a date and time, and you're apparently passing something else entirely based on your `Record 1: Time_Stamp is 1.2`. What SQL data type is `Time_Stamp` (in the DDL that created the column)? I know you've said that it's DATETIME, but you're not assigning DATETIME values to it (unless you mean to store 12/31/1899 at 4:48:00 AM).

Comment: @Ken White. Sorry for being unclear. I wrote 1.2 to emphasize the decimal issue. I am assigning TDateTime values to the DATETIME column. I extract 6 rows at a time for display on a serially connected terminal that can display 6 rows at a time. After six rows I scroll, and get another six rows based on the previous timestamp which can have decimals (milliseconds). The displayed format is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm.ss,zzz. Its the zzz part that is the issue. But this format is only used when I create the output. The problem concerns TDateTime vs ftDateTime and the Query.

Comment: @MartynA. That works. It seems there is a problem with Query.Parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Please chech the accuracy note for [SQL Server datetime and time data types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) on MSDN

It is written that:
Accuracy    Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds

This means
23:59:59.997
is OK
But 
23:59:59.998
will be rounded to 23:59:59.997
And 
23:59:59.999
will be rounded to 00:00:00 for the next day

Comment: I'm aware of the accuracy issues.  The decimal differences between the record are however in the tens to hundreds of ms.

Comment: I could not make Query.Parameters work. I rewrote that line, and it is now: WHERE (Time_Stamp >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-05-24 00:00:00.000',102))